# Google Play Game Services client setup and connecting

Tags: android, libgdx, google-plus, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've been working on game using the [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) framework and now I would like to set it up with the google play services to use leaderboards and set some achievements etc.

### First question:

To use the GamesClient library is it necessary to request a token or some kind of login to google?

### Second question:

I've created my client ID using the debug key, so I could easily test the game through eclipse. But I'm always refused to connect (GamesClient.connect()). I build the GamesClient through its Builder:

```
GamesClient.Builder gcb = new GamesClient.Builder(adView.getContext(), this, this);
                    gcb.setAccountName(accounts[0].name);
                    gcb.setViewForPopups(adView);
GamesClient gc = gcb.create();
```

Later when its time to call gc.connect(), it just calls the overriden onConnectionFailed();

I've added the meta-data to my android manifest, like this:

```
   <application
   ....
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
android:value="@string/app_id" />
   ....
```

The app_id content is the 12 digit or so from the client ID i've created for the game.(i've also tried with the full ID).

So I think thats not the problem.

More information:
[Client ID screenshot](http://imageshack.us/a/img268/4861/clientid.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All set! Finally after some tries without result, here is the method (suitable for libgdx users).

Answer to the First Question: There's no need at all to get requests or even use the AuthUtil class provided by google.

Answer to the Second Question:

Make sure to read some tutorials about GamesClient and its implementation.

Step1: Get the BaseGameUtils library provided by Google, [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples).

Step2: implement GameHelper.GameHelperListenner on your MainActivity, for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener
```

and declare a GameHelper that will do all the sign in work for you. (dont forget to call its constructor and setup method, see GameHelper class for more information).

Step3: call beginUserInitiatedSignIn() (from the GameHelper instance) to start the sign in flow.

Thats it!

Advice: Follow the Type-a-number game tutorial to understand the flow of sign in (instructions in the readme file) [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples).

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I was looking for.. (LibGdx rulez !)